# Sending Advanced Parameters to ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, request, url-parameters

I don't know how to phrase this question properly but basically I haven an ASP.Net Application. I send the following request to the controller from my view:

```
http://localhost:59112/Contacts/IndexJson?current=1&rowCount=50&sort%5BLastName%5D=desc&searchPhrase=&_=1490960196673
```

I have written two classes that are not working 100% as follows for a structure for this request data:

```
public class RequestData
{
    public int current { get; set; }
    public int rowCount { get; set; }
    public string searchPhrase { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SortData> sortItems { get; set; }
}
public class SortData
{
    public string Field { get; set; } // FIeld Name
    public string Type { get; set; } // ASC or DESC
}
```

Then in my controller I have the following:

```
public JsonResult IndexJson(RequestData model)
{
    /* Irrelevant code */
}
```

The model works and fills everything correctly except the `sortItems` returns null. How can I get the `sortItems` `Field` and `Type` defined in my class?

Since the parameter coming in from the `RequestData` is `sort[Field]=Type`.

### Edit

I changed my `RequestData` class to this:

```
public class RequestData
{
    public int current { get; set; }
    public int rowCount { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> sort { get; set; }
    public string searchPhrase { get; set; }
    public Guid id { get; set; }
}
```

Now the `model` holds the `sort` as `{[Field, Type]}` (an example of data).

If this is a good practice, how to I access `Field` and `Type`?

Comment: I tried editing your question as one of the classes doesn't have formatting.   Added 4 spaces but minimum edit is 6 !

Comment: Sorry, just approved an edit.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this a number of different ways; your problem in each case was simply not following the modelbinder conventions for that data type.

First and foremost, `IEnumerable` is out if you intend to post back to it. It's not an indexable type, so the modelbinder will never be able to bind to it. However, using something like `List` instead, is just fine. Then, your param names simply need to be in the format of: `ListProperty[N].Property`, where `N` is the index. So for your situation you could have used `sortItems[0].Field=LastName&sortItems[0].Type=desc`, and it would have bound just fine to your model.

For using a dictionary, your names should be in the format of `DictionaryProperty[N].Key` and `DictionaryProperty[N].Value`, where again, `N` is the index. In your scenarion that would look like `sort[0].Key=LastName&sort[0].Value=desc`.